# Spring Boot + Video error "video playback aborted due to a network error"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, video-streaming, streaming

So I've designed an application which has a reactjs frontend serving up content from a spring boot backend. I have a rest controller which serves up video. It works really well for about 10 minutes, and then I get "video playback aborted due to a network error" in my browser. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Should this be done on another thread or async or something? I imagine that's all done by spring.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class VideoDirectoryController {
@Autowired
private ConfigManager<LibraryConfig> librariesConf;

/**
 * 
 * @param libraryName
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/getVideo", produces = "video/mp4")
public byte[] getVideo(@RequestParam(value = "library") String libraryName,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName) {
    Library lib = librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().get(libraryName.toLowerCase());
    Video video = lib.getVideoFiles().get(fileName);
    lib.getRecentlyViewed().add(video);
    librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().keySet().forEach((libr) -> System.out.println("LIBR: :" + libr));
    try (FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream(lib.getFileDirectory(fileName))) {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As I said this works fine for about 10 minutes. It does it both if I use :3000 (the frontend) and if I directly hit the URL fetching the video (:8080/getVideo)

Any help is appreciated I've never worked with multimedia in Spring Boot before.

Comment: For starters don't read everything in memory and then return to client. Instead you should, imho, stream the content to the user. So inject the `HttpServletResponse` and directly write the content instead of reading it into memory.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum What do you think of StreamingResponseBody? This was something else suggested to me using IOUtils.copy, and enabling the AsyncTaskExecutor. Do you think there would be any problems with that?


Also surely since it's using an OutputStream Spring streams-on-demand instead of pushing it all to memory? I feel like it wouldn't load instantly were it loading 10GB video files into memory all at once. My comptuer is fast but...it's not that fast.

Comment: I was writing an answer just with that. Either will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [`StreamingResponseBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html) or to directly write to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletRequest`. Together with setting the content type and size of the response.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getVideo", produces = "video/mp4")
public void getVideo(@RequestParam(value = "library") String libraryName,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Library lib = librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().get(libraryName.toLowerCase());
    Video video = lib.getVideoFiles().get(fileName);
    lib.getRecentlyViewed().add(video);
    librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().keySet().forEach((libr) -> System.out.println("LIBR: :" + libr));

    try (FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream(lib.getFileDirectory(fileName))) {
        return StreamUtils.copy(out, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or the same using a `StreamingResponseBody`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getVideo", produces = "video/mp4")
public StreamingResponseBody getVideo(@RequestParam(value = "library") String libraryName,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName) {
    Library lib = librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().get(libraryName.toLowerCase());
    Video video = lib.getVideoFiles().get(fileName);
    lib.getRecentlyViewed().add(video);
    librariesConf.getConfig().getLibraries().keySet().forEach((libr) -> System.out.println("LIBR: :" + libr));
    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        public void write(OutputStream out2) throws IOException {
            try (FileInputStream out = new FileInputStream(lib.getFileDirectory(fileName))) {
                StreamUtils.copy(out, out2);       
            }
        }
    };
}
```